# Opposite of O_CREAT|O_EXCL

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

Is there way in C on Linux to only write to a file if it already exists? In other words, the opposite of `open(..., O_CREAT|O_EXCL)`.

Note that I don't want the existence check decoupled from the actual opening of the file (like calling `stat()` beforehand) because that would be a race condition.

Comment: Have you thought about, well, not passing those flags?

Comment: Have you tried calling `open` with only the `O_WRONLY` flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `ENOENT` while trying to open the file without the `O_CREAT` flag.

> ENOENT O_CREAT is not set and the named file does not exist; or O_CREAT is set and either the path prefix does not exist or the path argument points to an empty string.

Comment: Dear heavens. My brain must be turning into mush. Thank you all for answering even such a silly question.

Comment: Does this really answer the question? It seems you want to modify an existing file without creating a race condition where the file could be deleted before you open it.  If you do `open(O_CREAT)` and get ENOENT, it's the same as if you did `stat()` and discovered the file did not exist.  Then you have to open it to modify it, and there is the race condition again.

Comment: @ColinDBennett: The answer says "open the file *without* `O_CREAT`"; if that returns an error, the file did not exist, and the OP does not want to write the file, so there is no use-after-check. If it does not return an error, the file exists and is now open; again, no use-after-check.

Comment: @rici: Oh, you're right, my brain must be the one turning to mush. Thanks for the correction. Nice simple solution, no kludges involved.

Answer (score 1):

To do this I would try to open the file with O_WRONLY, if open() doesn't fail, the file exists. You can check errno to check the error.

I don't know any other way.

Comment: This still allows a race condition -- this is no better than using `stat()`: it still allows a race condition

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `fopen`, then:

```
file=fopen(some_sime, "r+");
if (file) fd=fileno(file);
```